# localStorage variable from Iframe only works in browser chrome or edge

Tags: reactjs, nginx, iframe, server

I have a call from an external website that invokes a route from my app as an iframe, this in turn runs a command on my website and logs me out, everything works fine in chrome and edge but in firefox and other browsers doesn't work, my variable from the localStorage gets undefined;

My component:

```
export default function AuthenticationLogout() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('token-logout', token);
        if (token && token !== '') {
        logout(token);
        }
    }, [token]);

    const logout = async (token: string) => {
        try {
          const authResponse = await AuthService.logout({ cid: token });
          if (authResponse[0]?.status === 'success') {
            history.push("/login")
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
    return (
        <>
            <p>Good bye</p>
        </>
        );
}
```

this is my nginx config:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"; 
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"; add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "master-only"; 
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://*.mydomain.com *.firebaseio.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 
frame-src 'self' https://*.mydomain.com/ https://externalweb.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com/;
manifest-src 'self'; 
media-src 'self'; 
worker-src 'self'; 
upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content; 
object-src 'none'"; 
add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"; 
add_header Pragma "no-cache";
```

I was trying to add

```
add_header X-User-Agent $http_user_agent;
```

but doesn't works